I have problem running a function that makes a button to change the background of a page
I have trouble running a function in JS that makes a button to change the page background.
Below is the pen's link:
https://codepen.io/Valt76/pen/rNgEgbe
Is there anybody that can kindly help me to figure out what is wrong?
Thank you very much in advance,
Valter
 <script>
function background1() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.banner').style.background = "url('./images/provabkgposter1.jpg') center center / cover";
}
</script>


Short version: querySelectorAll returns a Node List and not a single element. As it is a list, you need to iterate through the list to get every single element from it (even if the list is empty or just contains 1 element).

I suspect the bug pointed out by the duplicate is not your only problem. Are you trying to change the background of the banner to a different image depending on which button was clicked? Are those src's in your buttons what you want to change the banner's background to?

Are you au fait with using your browsers devtools inpsect facilty - in this case to see what Javascript erros there may be in the console?

Yes, it is correct. What I need to achieve is to change the page background (banner) depending on which button was clicked.

This is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'background')
at background1

No, these are the button backgrounds. The images for the banner are different (e.g. ./images/provabkgposter1.jpg)

@ValterPiso, that error is because  document.querySelectorAll('.banner').style is not defined, due to what @tacoshy mentioned about the Node List.
